# RFID reader reads only one time

Tags: rf, rfid

I have this module: [ebaylink](https://www.ebay.com/itm/184852958418). I have a problem: this reader reads only one time when a tag is in range. For example, when I drag a passive tag to the RFID reader, it reads one time and I want it to read one more time but it doesn't; this RFID reader does not read more than one time when an RF tag is in range.

I want it to read every tag more than one time when passive tags are in range. Here is an [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gzx0SZKJYE); this is working in the same way, I guess. The RFID reader module is waiting for the tag to go out of range before reading again.

I used the mfrc522 before; it reads everything when the tags are in range. when I put a tag on the mfrc522, it would read as long as the tag was within range.

How can I do the same? Is there a solution? Thank you.

[image]

Here is just what I want. I want to put the card in this way, and even if I do not move the card, I want the RFID reader module to read the tag continuously.

Comment: Thank you @ocrdu .

Comment: Have you tried using the reset pin after a read so see if that triggers a new read?

Comment: After you said, I find reset pin. It says Reset low level effective. I try to give high low high with 0.1 second delay and low high low with 0.1 second delay, doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, It worked. First low then high.